# Neo4j. Как поставить ограничение на число связей определенного типа в пути между двумя вершинами?

Tags: count, path, neo4j, cypher

Нужно найти путь, который содержал бы не более 2 связей типа "RT". 
При использовании следующего кода:

`MATCH (a:Tes1 { title: "a" }),(b:Tes1 { title: "b" }), p=shortestPath((a)-[r:BT|RT*]-(b))
WITH count(type(r)='RT') as cnt
WHERE cnt < 3
RETURN p;`

получаю ошибку:

**Type mismatch: expected Relationship but was List (line 2, column 17 (offset: 111))
"WITH count(type(r)='RT') as cnt"**

Я понимаю, что значит эта ошибка, но как сделать по-другому не знаю.
Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

`MATCH (a:Tes1 { title: "a" }),(b:Tes1 { title: "b" }), p=shortestPath((a)-[r:BT|RT*]-(b))
WITH p, filter(x IN relationships(p) WHERE type(x) = "RT") AS rtRels
WHERE size(rtRels) < 3
RETURN p;`

Comment: Это ответ или уточнение вопроса?